# How to use raspistill in signal mode programmatically?

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

I am experimenting with Raspberry Pi, camera, and raspistill utility.
Below is a fragment of JavaScript code executing under Node.js. The idea of this code is to launch Raspistill program in "signal" mode, cache the child process, and send a 'USR1' signal to it every time the sendSnapshot function is called. I expect the Raspisill to output a snapshot data to stdout, and I want to write that data to the http response stream. However, on('data', ) does not get called. What is wrong with my code?

```
private static raspistill = null;

public sendSnapshot(httpResponse: stream.Writable) {
    if (!Camera.raspistill) {
        console.log(this.getTimestamp() + 'Starting...');
        Camera.raspistill = spawn('raspistill', ['-w', '640', '-h', '480', '-q', '5', '-o', '-', '-n', '-t', '0', '-s']);  
    }

    Camera.raspistill.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        httpResponse.write(data, 'base64');
    });
    Camera.raspistill.stdout.on('close', (code) => {
        console.log(this.getTimestamp() + 'Closed...');
        httpResponse.end();
    });
    Camera.raspistill.kill('SIGUSR1');
}
```